# prove that the intersection of a family of topologies is also a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let { $\tau$}$_{i \in I}$ be a family of topologies on X
Therefore $\tau := \bigcap_{I \in I} \tau_i$ is a topology

Proof:

A topology $\tau$ on X is a family of sets with 3 properties

T1) ∅, X $\in \tau$

T2) closed under finite intersection

T3) closed under arbitrary union

So to proof T1)
Lets suppose

∅ $\notin \tau = \bigcap_{I \in I} \tau_i \implies \exists \tau_j : ∅\notin\tau_j$, it is a contradiction considering that $\tau_j$ is/ are topologies, the same logic can be applied to find out that X$\in \tau$

T2)
Let $A_1,A_2 \in \tau$ and suppose

$A_1 \cap A_2≠ \tau= \bigcap_{I \in I} \tau_i \implies A_1\cap A_2 \in ( \bigcap_{I \in I} \tau_i)^c= \bigcup_{I \in I} \tau_i^c$

Therfore every open of $\tau$ is a clopen, the problem is that I don't know if this is enough for a contradiction

Comment: Your title and your proof of $T1)$ suggest you're working with an intersection but the rest of your question - with the $\bigcup$ notation - suggests you're working with a union. What's going on?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I fix it

Comment: You don't need to use any contradictions, conclude that $\emptyset, X\in \tau$ directly from definition of intersection of sets

Comment: But the proofs I made with contradictions is wrong?

Comment: @MASSIMILIANOMESSINA It's not wrong, at least not all of the proofs, but it just makes it unnecessarily complicated

Comment: "Every open of $\tau$ is a clopen", this is false. I can see why you might say that but notice $\tau_i^c$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ which are not in $\tau_i$ - it is not the set of all subsets of $X$ whose complement is in $\tau_i$. And you couldn't get "every" anyway, not sure where that came from

Comment: I mistakenly regarded $\tau^c$ as the set of closed, and I said every because I Took 2 arbitrary open elements of $\tau$

Comment: You ask *But the proofs I made with contradictions is wrong?* Your proof of T2) certainly comes to a bad end; and since the direct proof is simpler, it was a strategic error to choose a proof by contradiction to begin with. I would say that a direct proof of T1) is also simpler than what you wrote.

Comment: I asked if T1's proof is false, I already understood that T2 is false but even so I don't know how to prove it differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us straightforwardly verify that the family $\tau$ satisfies the properties of a topology.

T1) For each $i\in I$ we have $\varnothing, X\in\tau_i$, so $\varnothing, X\in\bigcap_{i\in I} \tau_i=\tau$.

T2) Let $A,B\in\tau$. Then for each $i\in I$ we have $A,B\in\tau\subset\tau_i$. Since $\tau_i$ is a topology, we have that $A\cap B\in\tau_i$, so $A\cap B\in\bigcap_{i\in I} \tau_i=\tau$.

T3) Let $\{A_j:j\in J\}$ be a family of subsets of $\tau$. Then for each $i\in I$ and each $j\in J$ we have $A_j\in\tau\subset\tau_i$. Thus $\{A_j:j\in J\}$ is a family of subsets of $\tau_i$. Since $\tau_i$ is a topology, $\bigcup\{A_j:j\in J\}\in\tau_i$. Thus $\bigcup\{A_j:j\in J\}\in\bigcap_{i\in I}\tau_i=\tau$.

Comment: "Since τi is a topology, we have that A∩B∈τi⋂i∈Iτi=τ"

Comment: "Since τi is a topology, we have that A∩B∈τi⋂i∈Iτi=τ" A$cap$B why Is an element of that?

Comment: @MASSIMILIANOMESSINA I am sorry for the misprint and thank you for noticing it. I corrected the misprint.